# Use CoreImage to detect and replace a white border from an image?

Tags: ios, cifilter

Imagine you have a few hundred square images, say album cover art

> [image]

A few have a white border

> [image]

Notice the 10px or so border.

I was just about to write some trivial raster code to detect and remove such borders - simply, fill them in with gray.

But: could this be done in one swoop with core image in some way?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try to use CIDetector to detect the biggest rectangle. It is not a universal solution because this solution does not work good with images with big rects, but in your examples it works good:

```
- (CIImage*)processImage:(CIImage*)im
{
    CIContext* context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeRectangle context:context options:@{CIDetectorAspectRatio : @(1.0),
                      CIDetectorMinFeatureSize: @(180.0 / 225.0)}];
    NSArray<CIRectangleFeature*>* rectangles = (NSArray<CIRectangleFeature*>*)[detector featuresInImage:im];

    CIRectangleFeature* maxSizeRectangle = [rectangles firstObject];
    for (CIRectangleFeature* feature in rectangles)
    {
        if (CGRectGetWidth(maxSizeRectangle.bounds) * CGRectGetHeight(maxSizeRectangle.bounds) < CGRectGetWidth(feature.bounds) * CGRectGetHeight(feature.bounds))
        {
            maxSizeRectangle = feature;
        }
    }

    CIImage* result = im;
    if (maxSizeRectangle)
    {
        result = [im imageByCroppingToRect:maxSizeRectangle.bounds];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Main idea lies in options of the detector (in CIDetectorMinFeatureSize and CIDetectorMinFeatureSize), if minFeatureSize will be too small you can find wrong rects.
The code works good for examples that you's attached (black line around images is a background of the image views):
[image: result]